# preg_replace() error '/'. replace only the first match

Tags: php

I have this code to convert image url into image.

I want to convert only the first image, so:

```
if(preg_match('/(https?:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|png|gif))/', $titulo, $matches)){
    //$titulo = str_replace($matches[0], "<br><img src=\"$matches[0]\"><br>", $titulo);
    $titulo = preg_replace("/$matches[0]/i", "<br><img src=\"$matches[0]\"><br>", $titulo, 1);
 }
```

the problem is the preg_replace /$matches[0] is giving this error:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 36
```

and it is not working. any ideas why?

Comment: can you show us the value of `$matches[0]`?

Comment: @LioraHaydont it is an image.jpg url.

Comment: I use # instead of / and it works. don't know why.

Comment: There is no need to first call `preg_match()` then call `preg_replace()`.   Just do the latter, if there are no matches then nothing will be replaced.  That avoids the problems you're having when embedding the matched text into a regular expression string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$match[0] contains slash, which signs the end of expresion. You can change delimeters

```
"~$matches[0]~i"
```

to make [it work](https://eval.in/929690)s. But better way is to use `preg_quote` function which escapes "special" characters and symbols set as second argument (thx to @salathe comment).

Do it so to don't be afraid incorrect user's input:

```
'/'.preg_quote($matches[0], '/').'/i'
```

[about preg-quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

Comment: I use "#$matches[0]#" and it works. can I leave it with #?

Comment: If it never will be in your string

Comment: @splash58 you should use the second (`$delimiter`) argument for [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote), to make sure the pattern delimiter character (`~` or `|` in your examples) gets properly escaped rather than being mis-interpreted as a pattern delimiter.

Comment: Ok. You convinced me